# expressjs promise & sunc error handling

Tags: express, error-handling, es6-promise, parse-server

How do you handle sync errors and promise errors in the same code?
here is my code but am not sure its working fine, any ideas ?

```
helpers.list({
            limit: 1
        })
        .then(function(results) {
          // handle no results
          if (results.length < 1) {
            return next();
          }
            res.render('post/post');
        })
         .fail(function(error){
           next(error);
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sync errors and promises does not mix

the best solution I found will be to throw rejected promise so the fail() will catch it at the end

```
helpers.list({
            limit: 1
        })
        .then(function(results) {
          // handle no results
          if (results.length < 1) {
           // call next will go to next route , ie 404
           next();
            return Parse.Promise.reject('no results found')
          }
            res.render('post/post');
        })
         .fail(function(error){

           // call next(error); will invoke express error handler
        })
```